# No service for type 'Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.IResourceFilesSynchronizationManager' has been registered

Tags: publishing-service

I'd tried to disable the publishing service on my local 10.3 instance by doing the following:

> 1. Locate the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.config files and change the file extension to .disabled. The files can be found in the following folders:
>
>    - Sitecore XP 8.2: the /App_Config/Include folder.
>    - Sitecore XP 9.0: the /App_Config/Modules/PublishingService folder.
> 2. Switch to the Core database and rename the /sitecore/system/Aliases/Applications/Publish item to PublishDisabled.

But was getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that for 10.2 and above you need to take some additional steps to remove the dlls and .dat file:

> For Sitecore XP 10.2 and later versions:
>
> 1. Disable Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.config files in /App_Config/Modules/PublishingService folder
> 2. Remove Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.dll from /bin folder
> 3. Remove items.core.sps.dat from /sitecore modules/items/core folder.

more info here: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0154093